# Filter grid by text in EXTJS 3.2.1

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid in `EXTJS`. I need to add text-box and by the text to filter the grid.

**Here is my grid:**

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var reportsGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id: 'my-grid',

        cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([{
            id: 'CourseId',
            dataIndex: 'CourseId',
            hidden: true
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'ActionCenterId',
            hidden: true
        }, {
            header: 'AAAAA',
            width: 115,
            sortable: true,
            ,
            dataIndex: 'NameCourse'
        }]),
        {
            header: 'BBBB',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'ActionCenterName'
        },
        maxHeight: 350,
        autoHeight: true,
        width: 870,
        store: xmlStore,
        title: 'SEARCH'
    });

    reportsGrid.render('ext_grid_results');

    var xmlStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        url: "Services/course/courseService.aspx?serviceMethod=GetcourseDetails",
        reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
                record: 'Course',
                totalRecords: 'results'
            },
            record
        )
    });

    var record = Ext.data.Record.create([{
        name: 'CourseId',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'ActionCenterId',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'NameCourse',
        type: 'string'
    }]);
});
```

I want to add in the header text-box, which will filter the data as I type letters in the text-box. Please suggest me, how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a excellent paid plugin: http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-multisearch-plugin/